# OpenGL: how to set separate colour lighting for objects

Tags: opengl

How do I set individual lighting for each object in my scene, so that each object has its own color? Right now, when i set the lighting it lights up every object the exact same colour, but I want to set it so that  each object gets its own colour. Right now my scene looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3lMz.jpg

but I want it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXgiz.png

How do I set it so that the cube and the wave have their own separate colours?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the relevant rendering code.

Comment: set all object's material property and use it with lighting to calculate final color